# Mount existing azure file share as a persistent volume without using secret

Tags: azure, kubernetes, environment-variables, persistent-volumes, azure-files

The way to mount azure file as a PV is shown in tutorials as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: azurefile
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  azureFile:
    secretName: azure-secret
    shareName: aksshare
    readOnly: false
  mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=1000
  - gid=1000
  - mfsymlinks
  - nobrl
```

Currently I need to create a secret with the storage account key to get the pv working.
Is there a way to mount the file share without creating a secret, preferably using environment variables? For example, putting the account key in environment variables or using service principal credentials.

I also attempted to use kustomise secretGenerator to create the secret from env variables, but the secret name is different each time and I can't use it in the pv yaml file.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes is **secret** or **configmap** is one way of injecting secret only to deployments.

If you are storing something in secret that means you can access it as an environment variable.

You can create a storage class and use it something like:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: azurefile
provisioner: kubernetes.io/azure-file
mountOptions:
  - dir_mode=0777
  - file_mode=0777
  - uid=0
  - gid=0
  - mfsymlinks
  - cache=strict
  - actimeo=30
parameters:
  skuName: Standard_LRS
```

With this only you can add the secret so you don't have to add it multiple time.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. So how would I write the pv.yaml without using the secret?